# Game Theory: players' gender convention?

Tags: game-theory, convention

What is the Game Theory convention of using gender terms (male/female) for the players?

I found only one reference suggesting that odd-numbered players are male and even-numbered players are female.

Best regards,

Avner

Comment: Hmmm. Men. Odd, indeed. Seems right to me! ;-) (That's not intended to answer your question. I just couldn't resist calling them as I see them...)

Comment: It seems strange to use gender as an identifying factor in a language without grammatical gender. I've never seen such convention in my work in dynamic game theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that there is a common convention in the litterature. A good illustration of the divergence of opinions in the field can be found in the preface of [A Course in Game Theory by Osborne and Rubinstein](http://zhangjun.weebly.com/uploads/2/8/1/8/2818435/martin.pdf):

> "*A Note on Personal Pronouns*
>
> We disagree about how to handle English
>   third-person singular pro- nouns.
>
> AR [Ariel Rubinstein]
>    argues that we should use a
>   “neutral” pronoun and agrees to the use of “he”, with the
>   understanding that this refers to both men and women. Continuous
>   reminders of the he/she issue simply divert the reader’s attention
>   from the main issues. Language is extremely impor- tant in shaping our
>   thinking, but in academic material it is not useful to wave it as a
>   ﬂag, as is common in some circles.
>
> MJO [Martin Osborne] argues that no language is
>   “neutral”. In particular, there is a wealth of evidence, both from
>   experiments and from analyses of lan- guage use, that “he” is not
>   generally perceived to encompass both fe- males and males. To quote
>   the American Heritage Dictionary (third edition, page 831), “Thus he
>   is not really a gender-neutral pronoun; rather it refers to a male who
>   is to be taken as the representative mem- ber of the group referred to
>   by its antecedent. The traditional usage, then, is not simply a
>   grammatical convention; it also suggests a par- ticular pattern of
>   thought.” Further, the use of “he” to refer to an individual of
>   unspeciﬁed sex did not even arise naturally, but was im- posed as a
>   rule by (male) prescriptive grammarians in the eighteenth and
>   nineteenth centuries who were upset by the widespread use of “they” as
>   a singular pronoun and decided that, since in their opinion men were
>   more important than women, “he” should be used. The use of “he” to
>   refer to a generic individual thus both has its origins in sexist
>   attitudes and promotes such attitudes. There is no neat solution to
>   the problem, especially in a book such as this in which there are so
>   many references to generic individuals. “They” has many merits as a
>   singular pronoun, although its use can lead to ambiguities (and
>   complaints from editors). My preference is to use “she” for all
>   individuals. Obviously this us- age is not gender-neutral, but its use
>   for a few decades, after a couple of centuries in which “he” has
>   dominated, seems likely only to help to eliminate sexist ways of
>   thought. If such usage diverts some readers’ attentions from the
>   subjects discussed in this book and leads them to contemplate sexism
>   in the use of language, which is surely an issue at least as
>   signiﬁcant as the minutiae of sequential equilibrium, then an increase
>   in social welfare will have been achieved. (Whether or not this book
>   qualiﬁes as “academic material”, I see no reason why its readers
>   should be treated diﬀerently from those of any other material.)
>
> To conclude, we both feel strongly on this issue; we both regard the
>   compromise that we have reached as highly unsatisfactory. When re-
>   ferring to speciﬁc individuals, we sometimes use “he” and sometimes
>   “she”. For example, in two-player games we treat player 1 as female
>   and player 2 as male. We use “he” for generic individuals."

Answer (score 0):

Alice and Bob, A and B for short, genders can identify also.

Caroline
Dave,
Eve,
Fred,
Gail (sp?),
Hal,
Ingrid (not to be confused with Ingrip, God of CAPATCHAs),
Jack,
Kathryn (distinct from Caroline could be spelt with a C),
Luke,
Megan...

I should stop now